# Connection between directives(Angular 1.4.8)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I trying to prepare my SPA to Angular 1.5 for using components and for this reason i divided my page into 2 directives(components in the future) by this scheme:

**Playlist.html**

```
<playlist-managing></playlist-managing>
<song-list></song-list>
```

In the playlistManaging directive i should have a posibility to filtering songs which placed in the songList directive. So, what is the best way to do this? I can use an events in $scope, but i don't think that it's a good solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sharing data between directives has many ways,first and best way is to using Factory service and share data with that,the second way is the shared controller for directives,the third way is to keep the data in the parent controller of these directives and use a attribute to give the shared data into directives,the forth way is to using shared scope directives that share the scope between the parent controller and the directives here's the link of the ways above:

the shared controller :https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/directive-to-directive-communication

the Factory Service : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

the shared scope directives: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/11/understanding-scopes-in-angularjs-custom-directives.aspx

Comment: Thank you, i think that third way is the best approach for me

Comment: then use the isolated scope directives and '=' in scope Data : https://blog.umur.io/2013/07/02/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

Comment: yes, i know about two-way bindings in directives :)

Answer (score 1):

Directives in angularjs provide an **isolated scope** which is used to bind the data from the controller to the directives independently. So you can pass the scope from the controller to the directives using a two-way data binding through each directives. Here's some example of that:

First you need to initialize the scope in the controller :

```
.controller('playlistController', function() {
    $scope.songType = 'pop';
}
```

And then pass the **scope** into each directives via **isolated scope** with **two-way data binding** inside each directives:

```
.directive('playlistManaging').function({
    return {
        scope: {
             songType: '='
        },
        controller: function() {
             //some logic here
        }
    }
})

.directive('songList').function({
    return {
        scope: {
             songType: '='
        },
        controller: function() {
             //some logic here
        }
    }
})
```

Then connect the scope through the HTML attribute element.

```
//This is just a quick sample, the best solution is to define the controller inside angular routes
<div ng-controller="playlistController">
    <playlist-managing song-type="songType"></playlist-managing>
    <song-list song-type="songType"></song-list>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.